# Replace String from the End of an String | REGEXP_REPLACE()

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking (probably) for REGEXP_REPLACE() in BigQuery to remove specific strings from the end of another string.

I need to remove ".html" and ".htm"  and "/" (...plus a few more strings) from the end of the following URLs:

```
someurl.com/page.html
someurl.com/page.htm
someurl.com/page/
someurl.com/page/
```

I know I need REGEXP_REPLACE() but I'm too lame to build it.

Can someone give me a little push?

Thx!

DZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select 
  url, 
  regexp_replace(url, r'(.html|.htm|/)$', '') output
from t
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]